# Need to use a VAR inside an If

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the below code but I know it doesn't work as when I try declaring it, my code says it's not defined but I don't know how to write it.

I no I need to declare is before my `IF` statement but not sure how. Below is what I have but I know its wrong as I keep saying

```
if (Session["Step01Tel"] != "")
{
     var ContactDetails = Step01TelLabel.Text + " " + Session["Step01Tel"].ToString();
}
else if (Session["Step01Email"] != "")
{
     var ContactDetails = Step01EmailLabel.Text + " " + Session["Step01Email"].ToString();
}
```

Then I'm after something like the below in my code to call it as its for the body of my email that my site sends.

```
msg.Body = ContactDetails.Tostring()
```

The reason I'm after this is that if the Tel or Email field is empty then I don't want the Tel/Email label to be displayed in the email and you can not us an `If` inside an email body.

The below shows how I initially had it but as I said this displayed the field label with no value.

```
////NEED TO ONLY DISPLAY IF VALUE IS PRESENT
    //    Step01TelLabel.Text + " " + Session["Step01Tel"].ToString()
    //    + Environment.NewLine.ToString() +
    //    Step01EmailLabel.Text + " " + Session["Step01Email"].ToString()
    //    + Environment.NewLine.ToString() +
////
```

Comment: Search the actual compiler error you get. You'll find you'll need to declare `string ContactDetails` before your `if()`, and assign it inside.

Comment: Simply add `var ContactDetails = string.Empty` above your `if` statements (and remove the `var` inside).

Comment: @Henrik Could you please provide your solution as an answer.  New it would be easy, I was just getting a code blind by it and couldn't think of the solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
var ContactDetails = string.Empty;
if (Session["Step01Tel"] != "")
{
     ContactDetails = Step01TelLabel.Text + " " + Session["Step01Tel"].ToString();
}
else if (Session["Step01Email"] != "")
{
     ContactDetails = Step01EmailLabel.Text + " " + Session["Step01Email"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: Or just a `string ContactDetails;` - no need to assign something that will always be overwritten.

Comment: @HansKesting It doesn't work if I just use `string ContactDetails` so I need to assign it

Comment: @HansKesting if you don't assign an empty string you have to check for nulls later in the code. I think that assigning a reference to string.Empty is a tiny work that makes your code slimmer and easier to read.

Comment: @HansKesting It won't always be overwritten. It's possible that `Session["Step01Tel"] == "" && Session["Step01Email"] == ""`.

Comment: @deramko No, that's wrong. C# doesn't implicitly initialise `string` local variables to `null`, it requires you to initialise them and raises a compiler error if you don't. Perhaps you're thinking of fields, which do get initialised to `null` implicitly.

Comment: @mvd you are right, thanks.

Comment: True, it is possible that ContactDetails will not be (re)assigned - I forgot about that second if.